# How to create object which inherits from a parent object?

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
var A = {
  headers: {
    'a property' : 'a value'
  }
};
```

How I can create another object like this?

I do not want to type the whole parent object? My new object should contain the parent object, so when I `console.log` var A, B, and C it should produce different results.

```
var B = {
  headers: {
    'a property' : 'a value',
    'b property' : 'b value'
  }
};

var C = {
  headers: {
    'a property' : 'a value',
    'b property' : 'b value'
  },
  other: {
    other2: {
      'other2 property' : 'other2 property'
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: @Teemu little bit confuse on how to use it, may be you could answer it.

Comment: If you need a deep clone of the previous object when you extend it, you can use one of the many deep merge solutions posted for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically/41407737#41407737), for example the function I [posted there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41407737/5459839).

Answer (score 2):

You can use create function:

```
var B = Object.create(A);
B.headers['b property'] = 'b value';

var C = Object.create(B);
C.others = {
    other2: {
      'other2 property' : 'other2 property'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Should be `var C = Object.create(B)` no?

Comment: Just be aware that B and C share the `headers` object with A. If you change them via one, the change will be visible in the other as well. Note how this code adds the `b property` to `A.headers`.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is to extend the object `B` with the values already in `A`, you can use javascript object method `Object.assign` to do that like below :

```
var A = {
  headers: {
    'a property' : 'a value'
  }
};


var B = Object.assign(A);
B.headers['b property'] = 'b value';
```

This will copy the contents of source object i.e `A.headers` here into `B.headers` resulting below :

```
{
  headers: {
    'a property' : 'a value',
    'b property' : 'b value'
  }
};
```

Comment: Note how this code adds the `b property` to `A.headers`

Answer (score 0):

I always use [Simple JavaScript Inheritance by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) in my projects. It is a simple yet an elegant solution for the inheritance.

By using foregoing solution you can define your classes as follows. All you need to do is extending the classes.

```
var Person = Class.extend({
    init: function(isDancing) {
        this.dancing = isDancing;
    }
});

var Ninja = Person.extend({
    init: function() {
        this._super(false); // => Overrides the superior constructor
    }
});

var p = new Person(true);
p.dancing; // => true

var n = new Ninja();
n.dancing; // => false
```

It is also helpful since there is going to be an init method for all your classes so you are going to know where to bootstrap things, and how to override things properly.